# Checking If The Answer is True - Quiz App

Tags: android

I want to check if the given answer is right and prompt the final total true answers in another result layout. Here is some related snippets about this.

I wrote a method to check the answers.

```
public void isRightAnswer(List<String> rightAnswers){
    for(int k = 1 ; k< 10; k++) {
        int checkedButtonId = grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(grp_options.getChildAt(checkedButtonId).toString() == rightAnswers.get(k))
        {
            trueResult++;
        }
    }
}
```

In onCreate, i call the method.

```
btn_nextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nextQuestion);

isRightAnswer(rightAnswers);

btn_nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        promptTexts(optionAs, optionBs, optionCs, optionDs, questions);
        if(i==10){
            Intent intent = new Intent (QuizActivityAdjectives.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("trueResult", trueResult);
            startActivity(intent);
        }                   
    }
});
isRightAnswer(rightAnswers);
```

Edit: My ResultActivity class looks like this.

```html
public class ResultActivity extends Activity{

 TextView txt_result;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.result);
 
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String trueResult = intent.getStringExtra("trueResult");
  txt_result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt_result);
  txt_result.setText(trueResult);
  
 }
```

Logcat:

> 05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971): Process: org.example.ydsquizapp, PID: 11971
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.ydsquizapp/org.example.ydsquizapp.QuizActivityAdjectives}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at org.example.ydsquizapp.QuizActivityAdjectives.isRightAnswer(QuizActivityAdjectives.java:152)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at org.example.ydsquizapp.QuizActivityAdjectives.onCreate(QuizActivityAdjectives.java:118)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>   05-03 15:52:17.091: E/AndroidRuntime(11971):    ... 11 more

The program terminates i guess it is about that putExtra thing. I don't know..
trueRresult is a global member variable. If you don't understand i can put the whole code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we have log cat ?

Comment: instead of if(grp_options.getChildAt(checkedButtonId).toString() == rightAnswers.get(k))
use
if(grp_options.getChildAt(checkedButtonId).toString().equals(rightAnswers.get(k)))

Comment: Logcat added in the top post.

Comment: where have you initialized radio group : grp_options?

Comment: Inside the class before onCreate method globally described.  RadioGroup grp_options;

Comment: Why do you use `QuizActivityAdjectives.this` for starting an intent and not simply `this` ?

Answer (score 0):

As abihishesh said, use `equals()` to compare two Strings to each other. So your `isRightAnswer()` method would look like this:

```
public void isRightAnswer(List<String> rightAnswers){
    for(int k = 1 ; k< 10; k++) {
        int checkedButtonId = grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(grp_options.getChildAt(checkedButtonId).toString().equals(rightAnswers.get(k)))
        {
            trueResult++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an edit, the problem may be about my result class. Even when i do this the program terminates.

Comment: Although you use `.equals()` to comapre the Strings? The Exception is thrown, because of `isRightAnswer`. But you haven't copied the code for that part.